# Select Box onClick - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application that in the erb code, I use a select box. What I would like to do is reload the page passing the sort parameter. My controller already handles it, but I don't know how to reload the page with the selected value from my select box. Here is my code:

```
<% @options = {:latest => 'lastest' , :alphabetical => 'alphabetical', :pricelow => 'price-low', :pricehigh =>'pricehigh'} %>
<%= select_tag 'sort[]', options_for_select(@options), :include_blank => true,:onchange => "location.reload('location?sort='+this.value)"%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using an ajax call on your list box? If you have a method on your controller that returns just the sorted list, based on sort parameter, then you could do:

```
<% @options = {:latest => 'lastest' , :alphabetical => 'alphabetical', :pricelow => 'price-low', :pricehigh =>'pricehigh'} %>
<%= select_tag 'sort[]', options_for_select(@options), :include_blank => true,:onchange => remote_function(:url => {:controller => 'your_controller', :action => 'list_sort_method'}, :with => "'sort='+this.value", :update => "div_containing_list") %>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use AJAX, then put a form_tag around your code.

Take a look at the Redmine source code on http://redmine.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk. The UsersController does something similar - there's a combo box that allows a filter. Selecting the combo reloads the page.